# Perl regular expression for inconsistent XML attributes

Tags: xml, regex, perl

I am trying to write regular expression to capture from value field( string "male") for the two below lines using single regular expression

```
option selected="selected" value="***male***"

option value="***male***" selected="selected"
```

i have written some thing like,

```
option\s*?(?:value="(.+?)" selected="selected")|(?:selected="selected" value="(.+?)")
```

even though it is matching entire line from the file but "male" string is not captured. Please suggest.

Comment: use a xml parser dont use regex for xml files

Comment: what's wrong with XML::Twig?

Comment: [Mandatory Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3897316)

Answer (score 0):

```
local $/; $_ = <DATA>; $match=$_;
my @values;
while($match=~m/value="([^\"]*)"/g)
{
     push(@values, $1);
}
print join "\n", @values;

__DATA__
option selected="selected" value="***male***"
option value="***male***" selected="selected"
```

Comment: While this code-only answer may answer the question, it is usually better to give an explaination in addition to code.

Comment: I accepted your comments... Yes I should give an explanation about the code's.